# How to check if an anova test excludes zero values

Tags: r, anova

I was wondering if there is an simply way check if my zero values in my data are excluded in my anova.

I first changed all my zero values to NA with

```
BFL$logDecomposers[which(BFL$logDecomposers==0)] = NA
```

I'm not sure if 'na.action=na.exclude' makes sure my values are being ignored(like I want them to be)??

```
standard<-lm(logDecomposers~1, data=BFL) #null model
ANOVAlnDeco.lm<-lm(logDecomposers~Species_Number,data=BFL,na.action=na.exclude)
anova(standard,ANOVAlnDeco.lm)
```

P.S.:I've just been using R for a few weeks, and this website has been of tremendous help to me :)

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, the `subset` argument in `lm` may be relevant to you. E.g. `subset = logDecomposers != 0`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given a reproducible example, but I'll make one up.

```
set.seed(101)
mydata <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rlnorm(100))
## add some zeros
mydata$y[1:5] <- 0
```

As pointed out by @Henrik you can use the `subset` argument to exclude these values:

```
nullmodel <- lm(y~1,data=mydata,subset=y>0)
fullmodel <- update(nullmodel,.~x)
```

It's a little confusing, but `na.exclude` and `na.omit` (the default) actually lead to the *same* fitted model -- the difference is in whether `NA` values are included when you ask for residual or predicted values.  You can try it out:

```
mydata2 <- within(mydata,y[y==0] <- NA)
fullmodel2 <- update(fullmodel,subset=TRUE,data=mydata2)
```

(`subset=TRUE` turns off the previous `subset` argument, by specifying that all the data should be included).

You can compare the fits (coefficients etc.).  One shortcut is to use the `nobs` method, which counts the number of observations used in the model:

```
nrow(mydata)  ## 100
nobs(nullmodel)  ## 95
nobs(fullmodel)  ## 95
nobs(fullmodel2)  ## 95
nobs(update(fullmodel,subset=TRUE))  ## 100
```